# Django how to validate request in views against a model

Tags: django, django-views

In django models, There are n columns and in the views for save request ,then how to validate the fields against the model to check whether the request has all the mandatory variables, for ex:

models.py

```
class candidate(models.Model):
   name = models.IntegerField()
   college = models.TextField()
   city = models.TextField()
   state = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
   phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
def save(request):
   try:
     data = json.loads(request.body)
     if 'name' in data and 'college' in data and 'city' in data:
              //do something
```

Is this the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not marked the fields name, college, city as optional (ie blank=True or null=True) an error will be automatically flagged if these fields are missing.

However, if you want to perform custom checks across fields, then the best practice is to define a clean method to your model class, and invoke it before calling save.

```
class candidate(models.Model):
   name = models.IntegerField()
   college = models.TextField()
   city = models.TextField()
   state = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
   phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)

   def clean(self):
       if (self.name is None) or (self.college' is None) or (self.city is None):
            raise ValidationError('xxx')
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: @daniel shouldn't validation logic be placed in the model itself, so that regardless of input via forms or serializers (REST framework) the same validation code is re-used?

Comment: That would depend on how you are taking in user input - is it via a form on the website (as Daniel suggested), or via a mobile app over REST apis ?

Comment: Then I would suggest you read up http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ and install django-rest-framework. You will have to first create a file called serializers.py where you define a ModelSerializer class that corresponds to your model Candidate. Then, in views.py you can simply write generic views that mention which serializer to use to encode/decode the fields into JSON format. Lastly, map the url for the api to point to this view. The tutorial on Django rest framework is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

No. You use forms for that.

See the [documentation on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/) and [how to use them with models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: You use a framework designed for REST, then. As Tanuka suggests, Django Rest Framework.

Comment: so to summarize as stated in the question  views is the way to go about it .Right?

Comment: No. No-one said that, and it is not the case.